# Django Tenant Schemas "argparse.ArgumentError: argument --skip-checks: conflicting option string: --skip-checks"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multi-tenant

I faced the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233057/argparse-argumenterror-argument-skip-checks-conflicting-option-string-ski) but was unable to fix it from the answer provided with the question. I tried adding `tenant_schemas` to the end of `INSTALLED_APPS` like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = SHARED_APPS + TENANT_APPS + INSTALLED_APPS + ['tenant_schemas']
```

but this didn't worked. I moved `INSTALLED_APPS` to the bottom of the settings file and this also didn't worked.

The only option left for me is to copy the entire `tenant_schemas` library, fix it using the changes provided in the pull request in the answer, and connect it with the project as an app, which is a terrible way to proceed.

If there is an example for the solution provided in the above answer, or a better solution in itself, please let me know.

**TRACEBACK -**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\uniuno\uniuno\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\PycharmProjects\uniuno\uniuno\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 322, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 296, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tenant_schemas\management\commands\migrate_schemas.py", line 20, in add_arguments
    command.add_arguments(parser)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 26, in add_arguments
    parser.add_argument(
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1434, in add_argument
    return self._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1799, in _add_action
    self._optionals._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1636, in _add_action
    action = super(_ArgumentGroup, self)._add_action(action)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1448, in _add_action
    self._check_conflict(action)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1585, in _check_conflict
    conflict_handler(action, confl_optionals)
  File "C:\Users\Ishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1594, in _handle_conflict_error
    raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --skip-checks: conflicting option string: --skip-checks
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [argparse.ArgumentError: argument --skip-checks: conflicting option string: --skip-checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233057/argparse-argumenterror-argument-skip-checks-conflicting-option-string-ski)

Answer (score 0):

This error has a simple fix. The solution has already been proposed but the package is not being maintained since 2 years now and they won't merge the pull requests. So if you insist to use this package you will have to fork and make desired changes/fix.

I would suggest to switch from `django-tenant-schemas` to `django-tenants`. `django-tenant` is forked from `django-tenant-schemas` is being actively maintained.